# how can I pass an object to a function which should confirm two protcols in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I should be able pass an object which I created for eg:

```
Struct Response: Codable {

}

struct Obj: ProtocolB, ProtocolC {

let value: String
let name: String
let num: Int
}
self.request(obj: Obj.self, responseType: Response.self) // This i am able to do.

let ob = Obj(value:"hello",name:"alex",num:1)
self.request(obj: Obj.self, responseType: ob) // This I am not able to do
```

please suggest me how can i write a function which takes object which confirms both protocol A and B and takes the object.

```
func request<T: ProtcolA, X: ProtocolB & ProtocolC>(obj: X, responseType: T.Type) -> Promise<T> {
    let object = X.init() // This is not required but I am doing I should be able to use object directly.
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code nicely? It's quite a mess

Comment: you've switched around the arguments you're passing to the parameters `responseType` and `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question correctly, but having your method:

```
func request<T: ProtcolA, X: ProtocolB & ProtocolC>(obj: X, responseType: T.Type) -> Promise<T> {
    let object = X.init() // This is not required but I am doing I should be able to use object directly.
}
```

1. T and X are the generic types with its constraints, not the parameters. That means inside the method you have to use `obj` and `responseType`
2. `obj` is an **object** (conforming to ProtcolA) and `responseType`is a **type**, so you can't instantiate it
3. `obj` can be used normally inside the function (`let name = obj.name`)

But I'd like to ask you: why do you need two generic types? It'd be easier to help with some more information of what you're trying to do